# netbios routing

Tags: samba, routing

After a long time, I understood that isn't possible to routing netbios.
My scenario:

server1 192.168.100.212 <--> server2 192.168.100.213 (with 2nics 192.168.100.0/24 and 192.168.30.0/24) - static routing.

server1 has samba file server.

From network 192.168.30.0/24 I see and I work with samba server using \server\ and also using IP \192.168.30.212\

Problem is that from windows clients (all win version on 192.168.30.0/24 network) using network browsing (or net view command) I don't see netbios server.

iptables works fine.

```
domain master = no
preferred master = no
local master = yes
os level = 65
netbios name = SIGN
workgroup = WORKGROUP
Server String = SIGN
wins support = no
wins server = 192.168.100.212
wins proxy = yes
dns proxy = no
# check these
remote announce = 192.168.100.255/WORKGROUP 192.168.30.255/WORKGROUP
#remote browse sync = 192.168.100.212 192.168.30.212
name resolve order = wins bcast host dns
```

Comment: You should look at `nmdb` on server2 and configure it as a WINS server and maybe as a WINS proxy; also browser master.  `man nmdb` and `man smb.conf`

Comment: thank you. But I already have wins and proxy (on server1). Server 2 is only a static router.